# why does my make process show different behavior when a rule is included versus manually inlined

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which includes these two lines:

```
yank:
    mkdir yank
```

and when they are in the Makefile, the entire make process runs. But when I move them to a file included by this Makefile, then only the target 'yank' is made instead of the final target.

Entire makefile follows

```
include ../../Makefile.include


#VER  :=
AUTHOR := metaperl
PKG  := shell-current-directory
REPO := $(PKG)
GEST := $(PKG).elc
URL  := https://github.com/$(AUTHOR)/$(PKG).git

$(EDAN_EL) : $(WARES)/$(GEST)
    $(APPEND_EDAN) $(PKG) $(EDAN_EL) "`$(FILLIN) init.el --load_path $(WARES) --pkg $(PKG)`"

$(WARES)/$(GEST): yank/$(REPO)/$(PKG).elc
    cp $< $@


yank/$(REPO)/$(PKG).elc: yank/$(REPO)/$(PKG).el

yank/$(REPO)/$(PKG).el: yank/$(REPO)

yank/$(REPO) : yank
    cd yank && git clone $(URL)

yank:
    mkdir yank


$(phony clean):
    $(RM) -rf $(WARES)/gist.el
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target that is run when you simply type

```
make
```

is the **first** target found in the makefile. So if you have a target in your include file, that's going to be selected as the "default" target.

Just add a "dummy"

```
all: your_default_target_here
```

at the beginning of your file *before* the include or something to that effect.

Comment: I see. However, the default target is also defined in the top-level Makefile, so I cannot make it the default until the .include file is loaded in. [Here is the Makefile.include](https://github.com/metaperl/edan/blob/master/Makefile.include) and [here is the Makefile](https://github.com/metaperl/edan/blob/master/pkg/shell-current-directory/Makefile)